# Convert a row to variable names

Tags: matlab

Let's assume the following table: `mytable`. How could the first row be the variable names?

```
        Var1             Var2                   Var3          
    ___________    _______________    _______________________

       'Type'           'ID'                  'Number'
        'MF'           '99BM'                 '5999,3'               
        'MF'           '99LW'                 '3492,2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is currently in an array, the MATLAB command to create a table from an array is [`array2table`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html).

This command requires that your variable names are separated from the data itself:

`newtable = array2table(origarray(2:end,:),'VariableNames',origarray(1,:))`

If your data is already in a table, then you can use [`table2cell`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2cell.html) and table properties to extract the titles, then remove them from the table

`mytable.Properties.VariableNames = table2cell(mytable(1,:))`

`mytable = mytable(2:end,:);`